# How can I fill a block if a player has a score of 0 in an objective?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am making a hide and seek map and all I need to do is end the game when all hiders are eliminated. I have spent about 3 hours searching but my problem is that some PC commands don't work on Xbox One and all tutorials I found were for PC. Also, `[score_*objective name*=0]` does not work

Comment: Can you expand on what you have found?

Answer (score 0):

Nvm I found the answer. I detected when a player with a certain tag (hiders,seeker) spawned in a radius of the hub